# Create Database using Python on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, excel, database, pandas, csv

so i am building a database for a larger program and do not have much experience in this area of coding (mostly embedded system programming). My task is to import a large excel file into python. It is large so i'm assuming I must convert it to a CSV then truncate it by parsing and then partitioning and then import to avoid my computer crashing. Once the file is imported i must be able to extract/search specific information based on the column titles. There are other user interactive aspects that are simply string based so not very difficult. As for the rest, I am getting the picture but would like a more efficient and specific design. Can anyone offer me guidance on this?

Comment: I would use `pd.read_excel()` or `pd.read_csv()` and the `pandas` library in general

Answer (score 1):

An excel or csv can be read into python using `pandas`. The data is stored as rows and columns and is called a `dataframe`. To import data in such a structure, you need to import pandas first and then read the csv or excel into the dataframe structure.

```
import pandas as pd
df1= pd.read_csv('excelfilename.csv')
```

This dataframe structure is similar to tables and you can perform joining of different dataframes, grouping of data etc.

I am not sure if this is what you need, let me know if you need any further clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend actually loading it into a proper database such as [Mariadb](https://mariadb.org/) or [Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org). This will allow you to access the data from other applications and it takes the load off of you for writing a database. You can then use a ORM if you would like to interact with the data or simply use plain SQL via python.

Answer (score 0):

read the CSV

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
```

connect to a database

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("Any_Database_Name.db") #if the db does not exist, this creates a Any_Database_Name.db file in the current directory
```

store your table in the database:

```
df.to_sql('Some_Table_Name', conn)
```

read a SQL Query out of your database and into a pandas dataframe

```
sql_string = 'SELECT * FROM Some_Table_Name' df = pd.read_sql(sql_string, conn)
```